# Cross-Browser Event Handler (Add, Remove, Trigger)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome

I'm a little confused, when I try to Bind a Function to an event (like click) in IE7,IE9, Chrome 18, Firefox 12 it's work great, but when I try to remove the associated function to the event, only IE7 and Firefox are capable of dis-attach the function.
This is the code i'm using, what i'v doing wrong ??

```
    bindEvent:function(el,evtType,fn){

            if(el.addEventListener){
                el.addEventListener(evtType,fn,false);
            } else {
                if(el.attachEvent){


                  var _el=el;
                   var f = function(){fn.call(_el,window.event);}
                   el.attachEvent( 'on'+evtType, f);
                   el[fn.toString()+evtType]=f;


                    //el.attachEvent('on'+evtType,fn) ;

                } else {

                    el['on'+evtType]=fn;
                }
            }

    return el;

    },

    removeEvent: function(el,evtType, fn ) {

        if( el.removeEventListener){
            el.removeEventListener( evtType, fn, false );
        }else if(el.detachEvent){
            el.detachEvent('on'+evtType,el[fn.toString()+evtType]);
            el[fn.toString()+evtType]=null;


        }else{

            el['on'+evtType]=function(){};

        }

        return el;
    }
```

My codes to test this are:

```
var a = document.getElementById('just_a_div');
bindEvent(a,'click',function(){alert('Hi There');});
```

And to try to remove i use almost the same:

```
removeEvent(a,'click',function(){alert('Hi There');});
```

Any Ideas or some pre-made Snippets that can do this task efficiently on all browsers??
Hope a solution can appear, Eternally grateful.

Comment: For posterity, the OP code seems to be based on something posted by John Resig in September 2005. There are some substantial criticisms of the code in the comments, particularly those relating to memory leaks, which should be considered (e.g. those by [*Douglas*](http://ejohn.org/projects/flexible-javascript-events/#comment-5882)). They have not been addressed in the post. Also see the critique at [*What is wrong with this widely used AJAX event handler registration code?*](http://pankaj-k.net/weblog/2007/07/what_is_wrong_with_this_widely.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works in [my example](http://jsfiddle.net/FJc6G/) in IE8, firefox and chrome (the event will be removed after five seconds). Maybe you have an error in your testcase? Can you show us your testcase?

=== UPDTAE ===

In javascript *functions* are never the same also when they have the same parameters and content. Try: `alert(function(){alert('Hi There');} == function(){alert('Hi There');});` The result is `false`.

*Reverences to functions* are equal, if they reverences to the same function. So `var fn = function() { alert('clicked'); }; alert(fn == fn);` is `true`.

You should use the same refernce to a function in the `bindEvent` and `removeEvent` function like in [my example](http://jsfiddle.net/FJc6G/).

Comment: any ideas about why 5 seconds ??

Comment: Ohh, I've n  explore your code, It's a Timeout!!, sorry my mistake.

Comment: @codef0rmer the way i'm calling is: bindEvent('click',function(){return 'Hi';}); but when I try to remove it can be done, removeEvent('click',function(){return 'Hi';});

Answer (score 0):

It`s a little difficult to support all browser with your pure javascript code, too much better way is to use a javascript framework, I think one of the best is [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) & of course there are a lot of the other frameworks which have been designed for different purposes.

Comment: jQuery is not fully implements native javascript behaviour for event handling. With jQuery you can register same function more that one time for same event type of same object. But native behaviour of `addEventListener` does not allow this.

Comment: @AndrewD. But, the problem is that i just need to attach functions to object's event nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery for cross-browser support. You can simply attach an event using [.bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) and detach it using [unbind](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/).

Comment: That's precisely  my objective: DO NOT USE Jquery, i just need to attach functions to object's event.